# 1004 Runtime error when accessing checkbox

Tags: vba, excel, vb6

This question is related to VB in Excel 2003. My excel workbook references a VB macro. And, this macro has several user form. I've added a new checkbox control in one of the form. The problem is here, when I try to access the new checkbox through

```
ActiveWorkSheet.DialogSheet("Options").EdBox("CheckBox1").Text
```

it throws me a 1004 run-time error. My head is spinning to figure out why I can't seem to find out the root cause. There are already existing checkboxes, which are accessible without any issue. Any help is immensely appreciated.

Do I need to set any properties for the new CheckBox before I can access it from code?

Comment: Is the CheckBox in a user form on on the excel spreadsheet? And it looks like you're just trying to edit what the text is for it right?

Comment: Alex D, the user form is on the macro definition and my excel references this macro. I used the default "CheckBox1" name to just access it from my VB code to see if it works. But, it doesn't.

Comment: Are you actually using a DialogSheet, or a userform?  Haven't seen a DialogSheet since the old Excel 95 days though I know they're still supported.

Comment: I've to enhance an existing workbook. So, DialogSheet is used over there. And, I'm also using DialogSheet to access a CheckBox.

Comment: `.EdBox("CheckBox1")` looks wrong - have you tried `.CheckBoxes("CheckBox1")` instead?

Comment: May I see your workbook for a faster resolution?

Comment: All the existing CheckBoxes are accessed through .EdBox method of DialogSheet class.

Comment: I cannot share the workbook as its internal to the client I work for. I appreciate your concern.

Comment: For easier diagnosis, break down your method/property chain into parts.

Answer (score 1):

You have said that

> All the existing CheckBoxes are accessed through .EdBox method of DialogSheet class

so logically the 1004 error is due to there being no `.DialogSheet("Options")` or no `.EdBox("CheckBox1")` - most likely the latter.

In the Immediate pane enter:

```
?ActiveWorksheet.DialogSheet("Options").EdBox("CheckBox1").Name
```

and see if it pops the error. If it does then you will have to find the actual name of the CheckBox you added by looking at its' properties. Given that the form has other CheckBoxes, chances are that the one you added won't be named CheckBox1.